# Box.com - add box.com app to a specific folder

Tags: box-api, box

We have a client who is going to upload files to our box.com folder. As I understand I can use webhooks to trigger a POST request to my server as soon as someone uploads anything. Webhooks are setup inside box.com app that you need to create. This all makes sense. But how do I add my app to "monitor" that specific folder? Do I need to publish my app (I don't want to do that)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add my app to "monitor" that specific folder?

When you configure the webhook for `Upload` events, you can specify that Box should include the ID (`#item_parent_folder_id#`) of the folder that received the upload. On the server you can use this ID to monitor for uploads to a specific folder. (This assumes you know the ID of the upload folder in advance, and it sounds like you do.)

[image]

> Do I need to publish my app?

No, you don't need to publish the app.

Comment: I already did all of those steps and when I uploaded file to one of the folders nothing is triggering. I feel like I am missing a small step to somehow "map" the app and the folder if not the folder but the account in general.

Comment: You'll need to authorize the application to establish an association between your Box account and the app. Here's a [simple web app](https://box-oauth2-mvc.azurewebsites.net/) that performs the authorization workflow. Note that you must set your redirect_uri to https://box-oauth2-mvc.azurewebsites.net/ in order for that app to work properly.